# Aplicar função def em um dataset (iniciante)

Tags: python, funções, caracteres

Eu encontrei essa def aqui no stack, que resolve o meu problema com os caracteres

```
from urllib.parse import unquote

def cleanup(url):
    try:
        return unquote(url, errors='strict')
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        return unquote(url, encoding='latin-1')
```

por exemplo, o nome do filme Jo%C3%A3o.e.Maria.Ca%C3%A7adores.de.Bruxas..20..

```
>>> cleanup('Jo%C3%A3o.e.Maria.Ca%C3%A7adores.de.Bruxas..20..')

'João.e.Maria.Caçadores.de.Bruxas..20..'
```

**Agora eu queria saber se existe alguma forma de usar essa def em um dataset - ou seja, fazer com que "percorra" cada linha do dataset**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ps: eu aceito outra sugestões também, desde que converta os caracteres do meu dataset

Comment: É um dataframe pandas? Qual o nome da coluna?

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 1):

Veja o exemplo abaixo. O `apply` faz o trabalho todo.

### 1 - Mantenha a função exatamente como está

```
from urllib.parse import unquote

def cleanup(url):
    try:
        return unquote(url, errors="strict")
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        return unquote(url, encoding="latin-1")
```

### 2 - exemplo com pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

df["url"] = [
    "Jo%C3%A3o.e.Maria.Ca%C3%A7adores.de.Bruxas..20..",
    "Jo%C3%A3o.e.Pa%C3%A7oca.Jogam.futebol",
]
```

O dataframe estará assim:

```
                                                url
0  Jo%C3%A3o.e.Maria.Ca%C3%A7adores.de.Bruxas..20..
1             Jo%C3%A3o.e.Pa%C3%A7oca.Jogam.futebol
```

### 3 - Use o assign para criar uma nova coluna e o apply para aplicar a função

```
df = df.assign(clean_url=df["url"].apply(cleanup))
```

### Resultado

```
                                                url                               clean_url
0  Jo%C3%A3o.e.Maria.Ca%C3%A7adores.de.Bruxas..20..  João.e.Maria.Caçadores.de.Bruxas..20..
1             Jo%C3%A3o.e.Pa%C3%A7oca.Jogam.futebol             João.e.Paçoca.Jogam.futebol
```